# AvaloniaUI Repeat Button in touch devices

Tags: debian, touchscreen, avaloniaui, avalonia

I am trying to fix an issue with a button in my application built with AvaloniaUI for a touch device that works on Linux.

My problem with the existing button is:
when the user touches the button with his finger and holds on, the event is repeated while the user holding the button, and this is not the desired behavior.
I want to force the user to touch the button every time he wants the event to be fired.

I am not sure if this kind of touch handling is available.
Here is my code:
XAML:

```
... 
<Button Name="btnIncrement" Content="Increment" />
<Label Name="lblCount" />
...
```

C# Code:

```
...
btn = this.FindName<Button>("btnIncrement");
lbl = this.FindName<Label>("lblCount");
...
private void btnClick(object sernder, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   lblCount.Content = ++Counter;
}
```

**UPDATE**
Here are the outputs of the command `evtest` when I hold my finger on a button (generally screen) also I can see the effect of clicking a button repeated on the screen.

```
No device specified, trying to scan all of /dev/input/event*
Not running as root, no devices may be available.
Available devices:
/dev/input/event0:  mXT Touch Sensor
Select the device event number [0-0]: 0
Input driver version is 1.0.1
Input device ID: bus 0x0 vendor 0x0 product 0x0 version 0x0
Input device name: "mXT Touch Sensor"
Supported events:
  Event type 0 (EV_SYN)
  Event type 1 (EV_KEY)
    Event code 330 (BTN_TOUCH)
  Event type 3 (EV_ABS)
    Event code 0 (ABS_X)
      Value      0
      Min        0
      Max     1023
    Event code 1 (ABS_Y)
      Value      0
      Min        0
      Max      599
    Event code 24 (ABS_PRESSURE)
      Value      0
      Min        0
      Max       30
    Event code 47 (ABS_MT_SLOT)
      Value      0
      Min        0
      Max        2
    Event code 48 (ABS_MT_TOUCH_MAJOR)
      Value      0
      Min        0
      Max      255
    Event code 52 (ABS_MT_ORIENTATION)
      Value      0
      Min        0
      Max      255
    Event code 53 (ABS_MT_POSITION_X)
      Value      0
      Min        0
      Max     1023
    Event code 54 (ABS_MT_POSITION_Y)
      Value      0
      Min        0
      Max      599
    Event code 57 (ABS_MT_TRACKING_ID)
      Value      0
      Min        0
      Max    65535
    Event code 58 (ABS_MT_PRESSURE)
      Value      0
      Min        0
      Max       30
Properties:
  Property type 1 (INPUT_PROP_DIRECT)
Testing ... (interrupt to exit)
Event: time 1627091349.970937, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 57 (ABS_MT_TRACKING_ID), value 312
Event: time 1627091349.970937, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 53 (ABS_MT_POSITION_X), value 134
Event: time 1627091349.970937, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 54 (ABS_MT_POSITION_Y), value 36
Event: time 1627091349.970937, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1627091350.037757, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 57 (ABS_MT_TRACKING_ID), value -1
Event: time 1627091350.037757, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1627091350.059211, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 57 (ABS_MT_TRACKING_ID), value 313
Event: time 1627091350.059211, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 53 (ABS_MT_POSITION_X), value 129
Event: time 1627091350.059211, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 54 (ABS_MT_POSITION_Y), value 40
Event: time 1627091350.059211, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1627091350.108717, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 57 (ABS_MT_TRACKING_ID), value -1
Event: time 1627091350.108717, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1627091350.130538, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 57 (ABS_MT_TRACKING_ID), value 314
Event: time 1627091350.130538, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 53 (ABS_MT_POSITION_X), value 127
Event: time 1627091350.130538, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 54 (ABS_MT_POSITION_Y), value 36
Event: time 1627091350.130538, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1627091350.816930, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 57 (ABS_MT_TRACKING_ID), value -1
Event: time 1627091350.816930, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1627091350.838510, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 57 (ABS_MT_TRACKING_ID), value 315
Event: time 1627091350.838510, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 53 (ABS_MT_POSITION_X), value 130
Event: time 1627091350.838510, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 54 (ABS_MT_POSITION_Y), value 32
Event: time 1627091350.838510, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1627091351.204381, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 57 (ABS_MT_TRACKING_ID), value -1
Event: time 1627091351.204381, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1627091351.225845, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 57 (ABS_MT_TRACKING_ID), value 316
Event: time 1627091351.225845, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 53 (ABS_MT_POSITION_X), value 138
Event: time 1627091351.225845, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 54 (ABS_MT_POSITION_Y), value 35
Event: time 1627091351.225845, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1627091351.317391, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 57 (ABS_MT_TRACKING_ID), value -1
Event: time 1627091351.317391, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1627091351.338715, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 57 (ABS_MT_TRACKING_ID), value 317
Event: time 1627091351.338715, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 53 (ABS_MT_POSITION_X), value 152
Event: time 1627091351.338715, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 54 (ABS_MT_POSITION_Y), value 24
Event: time 1627091351.338715, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1627091351.658090, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 53 (ABS_MT_POSITION_X), value 131
Event: time 1627091351.658090, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 54 (ABS_MT_POSITION_Y), value 35
Event: time 1627091351.658090, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1627091351.671549, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 53 (ABS_MT_POSITION_X), value 129
Event: time 1627091351.671549, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1627091351.678810, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 53 (ABS_MT_POSITION_X), value 127
Event: time 1627091351.678810, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1627091351.867264, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 53 (ABS_MT_POSITION_X), value 138
Event: time 1627091351.867264, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1627091351.874466, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 53 (ABS_MT_POSITION_X), value 139
Event: time 1627091351.874466, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1627091351.888508, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 53 (ABS_MT_POSITION_X), value 140
Event: time 1627091351.888508, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1627091351.909537, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 53 (ABS_MT_POSITION_X), value 141
Event: time 1627091351.909537, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1627091351.951345, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 57 (ABS_MT_TRACKING_ID), value -1
Event: time 1627091351.951345, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1627091351.979997, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 57 (ABS_MT_TRACKING_ID), value 318
Event: time 1627091351.979997, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 53 (ABS_MT_POSITION_X), value 129
Event: time 1627091351.979997, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 54 (ABS_MT_POSITION_Y), value 29
Event: time 1627091351.979997, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1627091352.071894, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 57 (ABS_MT_TRACKING_ID), value -1
Event: time 1627091352.071894, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1627091352.294553, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 57 (ABS_MT_TRACKING_ID), value 319
Event: time 1627091352.294553, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 53 (ABS_MT_POSITION_X), value 144
Event: time 1627091352.294553, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 54 (ABS_MT_POSITION_Y), value 36
Event: time 1627091352.294553, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1627091352.517442, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 57 (ABS_MT_TRACKING_ID), value -1
Event: time 1627091352.517442, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1627091352.549481, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 57 (ABS_MT_TRACKING_ID), value 320
Event: time 1627091352.549481, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 53 (ABS_MT_POSITION_X), value 145
Event: time 1627091352.549481, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 54 (ABS_MT_POSITION_Y), value 41
Event: time 1627091352.549481, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1627091352.591606, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 57 (ABS_MT_TRACKING_ID), value -1
Event: time 1627091352.591606, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1627091352.656656, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 57 (ABS_MT_TRACKING_ID), value 321
Event: time 1627091352.656656, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 53 (ABS_MT_POSITION_X), value 133
Event: time 1627091352.656656, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 54 (ABS_MT_POSITION_Y), value 35
Event: time 1627091352.656656, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1627091352.716603, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 57 (ABS_MT_TRACKING_ID), value -1
Event: time 1627091352.716603, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1627091352.745165, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 57 (ABS_MT_TRACKING_ID), value 322
Event: time 1627091352.745165, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 53 (ABS_MT_POSITION_X), value 141
Event: time 1627091352.745165, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 54 (ABS_MT_POSITION_Y), value 38
Event: time 1627091352.745165, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1627091352.779854, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 57 (ABS_MT_TRACKING_ID), value -1
Event: time 1627091352.779854, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1627091352.830165, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 57 (ABS_MT_TRACKING_ID), value 323
Event: time 1627091352.830165, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 53 (ABS_MT_POSITION_X), value 149
Event: time 1627091352.830165, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 54 (ABS_MT_POSITION_Y), value 34
Event: time 1627091352.830165, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1627091352.903828, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 57 (ABS_MT_TRACKING_ID), value -1
Event: time 1627091352.903828, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1627091352.929689, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 57 (ABS_MT_TRACKING_ID), value 324
Event: time 1627091352.929689, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 53 (ABS_MT_POSITION_X), value 129
Event: time 1627091352.929689, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1627091353.335710, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 57 (ABS_MT_TRACKING_ID), value -1
Event: time 1627091353.335710, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1627091353.357271, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 57 (ABS_MT_TRACKING_ID), value 325
Event: time 1627091353.357271, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 53 (ABS_MT_POSITION_X), value 132
Event: time 1627091353.357271, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 54 (ABS_MT_POSITION_Y), value 36
Event: time 1627091353.357271, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1627091353.487983, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 57 (ABS_MT_TRACKING_ID), value -1
Event: time 1627091353.487983, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
```

Comment: Cant reproduce this with my laptop's touchscreen. Run `xinput2 test-xi2` utility to make sure that your touch device doesn't generate pointer any TouchEnd/TouchBegin events while user is holding a finger.

Comment: @kekekeks the xinput command does not exist because I am using a different image without XWindow.
There are, however, the libinput-debug-events

event0   TOUCH_DOWN        +1.70s      0 (0) 40.53/28.67 (415.00/172.00mm)
event0   TOUCH_FRAME       +1.70s
event0   TOUCH_UP          +1.85s
event0   TOUCH_FRAME       +1.85s
event0   TOUCH_DOWN        +1.88s      0 (0) 40.62/29.67 (416.00/178.00mm)
event0   TOUCH_FRAME       +1.88s
event0   TOUCH_UP          +1.90s.

Comment: Did you tap twice? Because libinput output looks like you've tapped twice with 180ms interval.

Comment: @kekekeks No, just holding my finger, and if I hold and drag i get only one down and one up event. BUT if I keep holding I get that result a series of up/down

Comment: @kekekeks can I configure libinput or use tsinput to resolve such a problem?

Comment: Try using `evtest`, it will show you raw events from the kernel. If you'll see `type 1 (EV_KEY), code 330 (BTN_TOUCH), value 0` while holding your finger on the screen, that means that either touchscreen itself or its driver is malfunctioning.

Comment: @kekekeks here is the output it got (EV_ABS):
time 1627077621.328223, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 57 (ABS_MT_TRACKING_ID), value 102
time 1627077621.328223, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 53 (ABS_MT_POSITION_X), value 177
time 1627077621.328223, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 54 (ABS_MT_POSITION_Y), value 41
time 1627077621.328223, -- SYN_REPORT ---
time 1627077621.525729, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 57 (ABS_MT_TRACKING_ID), value -1
time 1627077621.525729, -- SYN_REPORT
time 1627077622.139376, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 57 (ABS_MT_TRACKING_ID), value -1
time 1627077622.139376, -- SYN_REPORT --

Comment: @kekekeks and here is the output of a one click with my finger on the screen:

Event: time 1627077501.112508, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 57 (ABS_MT_TRACKING_ID), value 101
Event: time 1627077501.112508, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 53 (ABS_MT_POSITION_X), value 172
Event: time 1627077501.112508, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 54 (ABS_MT_POSITION_Y), value 18
Event: time 1627077501.112508, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1627077501.223639, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 57 (ABS_MT_TRACKING_ID), value -1
Event: time 1627077501.223639, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------

Comment: @kekekeks and here is my os details:
  Operating System: Debian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch)
            Kernel: Linux 4.9.11-v1.720+
      Architecture: arm

Comment: @kekekeks and this is how my 40-libinput.conf file looks like:
Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "libinput pointer catchall"
        MatchIsPointer "on"
        MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
        Driver "libinput"
EndSection
Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "libinput keyboard catchall"
        MatchIsKeyboard "on"
        MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
        Driver "libinput"
EndSection

Comment: Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "libinput touchpad catchall"
        MatchIsTouchpad "on"
        MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
        Driver "libinput"
EndSection
Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "libinput touchscreen catchall"
        MatchIsTouchscreen "on"
        MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
        Driver "libinput"
EndSection
Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "libinput tablet catchall"
        MatchIsTablet "on"
        MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"

Comment: (ABS_MT_TRACKING_ID), value 102 time 1627077621.328223;
ABS_MT_TRACKING_ID), value -1 time 1627077621.525729;

Comment: Those lines mean that touch contact was lost in 200ms. So it's not libinput's fault, it's either faulty hardware or faulty driver.

Comment: See https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/input/multi-touch-protocol.txt for more details on multi-touch events printed by evtest.

Comment: Try using `mxt-app` to calibrate your device. `--self-cap-tune-config` option looks like something that might help.